# Can i make retrieve request in django from model parameter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django rest framework for my api. In my views.py file i am using Viewset.ModelViewset.

```
class SchemaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.Schema.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchemaSerializer
```

My URL for this is : http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/schema/
THis is giving me GET and POST option. The response is something like this:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "yatharth",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
```

To Delete/Put/Patch i have to pass id which is 1 like this:  http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/schema/1/.
Can i do this by name like this: http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/schema/yatharth/ instead of id.

My model.py (I can Set name to unique = True)

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    """Database model for Schema """


    name= models.TextField()
    version = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I need id parameter also, so removing it isn't an option but instead of making query by id, i need to make it by name (both are unique)

what i found on django rest framework documentation

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But don't know how to change primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set do this by setting lookup_field = 'name' in your SchemaViewSet.

eg

```
class SchemaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.Schema.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchemaSerializer
    lookup_field = 'name'
```